# Taiwan Windows10 usable in English?

Tags: windows-10, language-pack

I will be in Taiwan on business soon and am looking to purchase a Taiwanese brand laptop as a gift for a native English speaker. The laptop would come preinstalled with Windows 10.

I know that English Windows 10 can install East Asian language support without any trouble, but I don't know if a Taiwanese Win10 install can be "converted" to fully English (all menus, folder names, etc.) on first run?

Failing that, would the OEM license key support reinstallation of an ENG ISO?

Comment: Provided the Windows license is not for Single Language, then the English version [ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) can be utilized to reinstall Windows in English

Comment: @JQ0914, is there a way to determine that license status before purchase?

Comment: Unless the license is from an authorized seller (i.e. authorized by Microsoft as a reseller), probably not, since one would have to know the license key to  verify it's legitimacy.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you purchased the Windows 10 Home Single Language edition,
other Windows 10 versions should support user interface language changes to English version. 
There are even hacks for Single Language version. 
See [How to change Windows 10 interface language
on Single Language version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31700488/4551050) to switch, but that might require some IT skill.